# Foreign key fields in Entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, entity

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and spend some time on creating forms for entities with related entities.

While looking for the best way to achieve this, I figured out that most examples on the Internet use an ugly way of referencing related objects.

For example, see this excerpt of the [MVC Music Store tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store):

[http://s8.postimage.org/mmevixep1/orm_mvc.png http://s8.postimage.org/mmevixep1/orm_mvc.png](http://s8.postimage.org/mmevixep1/orm_mvc.png)

I found the same approach in other tutorials too, for example [this one](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) ("Modifying the Course Entity", there is a DepartmentID and an Department object).

I was confused about the fact that the whole idea behind ORM is dropped here. **But I also found out that it's not (or hardly) possible to update a related entity without 'foreign key properties'.**

Can someone explain why Microsoft uses this approach, and whether there are alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign key fields don't have to be included in the model. Actually, this functionality was only included in .Net 4.0. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee373856%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has a god explanation about relationships in .Net Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know both methods are accepted. But I am still wondering how I can update related entities from a form. All examples I found use this 'foreign key field' approach. Problem is that related entities are not automatically detected upon postback. But thanks anyway! ;)